# Android app appearing different on real device vs emulator

Tags: java, android

Just coding a small app which currently has a bunch of textviews all constrained together.

When running in the emulator with the same specs as the device I'm using (Galaxy Tab A) it runs perfectly fine and outputs the same as the design view in Android Studio.

However when i run the same app on the actual device the app appears to be zoomed in with the bottom and right edges cropped.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Thanks for any help

Comment: create multiple screen size xml with the same name... or use ConstraintLayout..

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Comment: I am using ConstraintLayout, it appears perfectly fine in the emulator just when i run it on the actual device it is cropped and zoomed in to the top left .

Comment: Does your device drawing at the bottom the navigation bar the same that the emulator or it is hidden at the emulator?

Comment: What do you mean walter?

Answer (score 0):

Android powers hundreds of device types with several different screen sizes, ranging from small phones to large TV sets. Therefore, it’s important that you design your application to be compatible with all screen sizes so it’s available to as many users as possible. It must optimize the user experience for each screen configuration.

Checkout this awesome tutorial about [Designing for Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html) for more details.

> Starting with Android 1.6 (API Level 4), Android provides support for
>   multiple screen sizes and densities, reflecting the many different
>   screen configurations that a device may have. You can use features of
>   the Android system to optimize your application's user interface for
>   each screen configuration and ensure that your application not only
>   renders properly, but provides the best user experience possible on
>   each screen.

Check this android official document for [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) to get more information about it.

Comment: I am only targetting one specific screen size as this app will only be used internally on one specific device.As i said previously it shows up perfectly fine in the emulator just not on the actual device.